# Equation counter does not work

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

My references for equations do not work. The numbers on the right side to the equation are fine, but the references all show 3.1.2 (which does not exist...)

I show you my complete header with a short example

```
%Dokumentklasse/-Einstellungen
\documentclass[%draft,
pdftex,12pt,twoside,a4paper,parskip,headsepline,headings=small,%
numbers=noenddot,bibliography=totoc,openright,cleardoublepage=current,headinclude=true,footinclude=false%,tablecaptionsabove
]{scrreprt}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries\upshape\boldmath}


\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize}

\usepackage%[showframe]
{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\let\raggedsection\relax
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{float} % force pictures in pos

%caption-Einstellungen
\usepackage[format=plain%,margin=10pt
,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=quad
,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false%,figureposition=bottom,tableposition=top
]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}


\usepackage{layouts}

\renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{\addvspace{-2\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{0.75\baselineskip}}

%ToC formatieren (für DIN-gerechtes ToC)
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1.\baselineskip}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{3em}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\cftsetindents{section}{3em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{4em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{4em}{3em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@pnumwidth}{2em}% Breite der Box für Seitenzahlen im Inhaltsverzeichnis erhöhen (bei dreistellig-Seiten-Doks)
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\makeatother

%restliche Pakete
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}            % verbesserter Formelsatz
\usepackage{amssymb}            % verbesserter Formelsatz
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0} 
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{lightblue1}{rgb}{0.2,0.8,0.99}
\definecolor{lightblue2}{rgb}{0.1,0.4,0.9}
\definecolor{black1}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{appendix} %for appendix obviously
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
%for inclusion of gnumeric tables:
\def\inputGnumericTable{}
\usepackage{array}                                            
\usepackage{lscape}                                        
\usepackage{calc}                                             
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{hhline}                     
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{textcomp}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \beta (E) = \frac{1}{T(E)}  = \frac{\partial S}{ \partial E } \approx \frac{S(E+\epsilon) - S(E)}{\epsilon}
\end{equation}\label{eq:stepone}%
\begin{equation}
  W_0^{i+1}(E) = c \frac{W^{i}(E)}{H^i(E)} = e^{-S_0^{i+1}(E)}
\end{equation}\label{eq:steptwo}%
check: \ref{eq:stepone}, \ref{eq:steptwo} 


\end{document}
```

In this case the labels shown in the aux-file are just empty.. Any ideas?

Comment: The "3.1.2" string in the cross-references isn't produced by your code. In all likelihood, though, it's the number of the subsection that contains your equations. The fact that a subsection number shows up as the cross-reference should be a dead give-away that your use of (at least two) `\label` statements is syntactically invalid. Indeed, as @Werner shows in his answer, the equation-related `\label` statements must occur *inside* the respective `equation` environments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\label` has to be *within* the `equation` environment. While you place it on the same line as `\end{equation}`, it's technically *outside* the environment.

So use something like

```
\begin{equation}
  % your equation here
  \label{<label>}
\end{equation}
```